# Group MySQL rows by month and count data until each month

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table called "results" with lots of rows and a column called "timestamp".

I want to group the number of rows for each month. But for each one of them, I also want to consider the previous months rows.

So if I have

```
Jun/13
Jun/13
Jun/13
Jul/13
Jul/13
Jul/13
Jul/13
Jul/13
Aug/13
Aug/13
Aug/13
Aug/13
Aug/13
Aug/13
Aug/13
```

The result will be

```
3  Jun/13
8  Jul/13
15 Aug/13
```

This is what I have right now, but it doesn't consider the previous months.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp), '%e %b %Y'), COUNT(1) FROM results
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp), '%e %b %Y');
```

Comment: change COUNT(1) to COUNT(*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this to work:

```
SELECT month, count, @total:=@total+count AS total
FROM (SELECT @total:=0) t STRAIGHT_JOIN
  (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp), '%e %b %Y') AS month, COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM results GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))) AS m;

+------------+-------+-------+
| month      | count | total |
+------------+-------+-------+
| 1 Jun 2013 |     3 |     3 |
| 1 Jul 2013 |     5 |     8 |
| 1 Aug 2013 |     7 |    15 |
+------------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

the following solution should be work ...

SELECT COUNT(1), DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%b/%y') FROM results
GROUP BY YEAR(timestamp), MONTH(timestamp);

good luck

Talki

Comment: The result is the same of the query I posted... it doesn't consider previous months

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this should work;

```
SELECT COUNT(*) num, SUBSTR(ts, 1, 7) month
FROM results
JOIN (SELECT MAX(timestamp) ts FROM results
      GROUP BY YEAR(timestamp),Month(timestamp)) mm
  ON results.timestamp <= mm.ts
GROUP BY SUBSTR(ts, 1, 7);
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79824/1).